# How can i run Angular Dockerfile project?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

im trying to create an angular app with a node dockerfile.

I have an angular project created manually with angular cli on my computer filesystem, from which I copy it to docker container.

Dockerfile-angular:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY packages.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./web .
RUN npm build
EXPOSE 3000 4200
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

server.js:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
// Constants
const PORT = 3000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});
app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "docker container for node project",
  "author": "Alberto Sanmartin Martinez",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  angular:
    container_name: youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-angular
      restart: unless-stopped
      command: npm run start --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 4200:4200
```

The error that appears is:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! youngtalentreturn@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "0.0.0.0" "4200"`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the youngtalentreturn@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-06T09_51_17_529Z-debug.log
```

I can access through browser to 0.0.0.0:3000 but not to Angular app

Anybody could help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check in the resulting image what's in `/usr/src/app`? There are some suspicious things here. You are calling `node start`, but I see no `start.js` script. There's an error message about `/usr/src/app/ng`, but I see no reference to `ng` in your Dockerfile or `package.json`.

Comment: Update previos error, but appears another new.